# Difference in URL decode/encode UTF-8 between Java and JS/AS3 (bug!?)

Tags: java, javascript, encoding, unicode-escapes

I am having an issue URL decoding a UTF-8 string in Java that is encoded either with Javascript or Actionscript 3. I've set up a test case as follows:

The string in question is Produktgröße

When I encode with JS/AS3 I get the following string:

```
escape('Produktgröße')
```

Produktgr%F6%DFe

When I unescape this with JS I get no change

```
unescape('Produktgr%F6%DFe')
```

Produktgr%F6%DFe

So, by this I assume that JS isn't encoding the string properly??

The following JSP produces this outupt

```
<%@page import="java.net.URLEncoder"%>
<%@page import="java.net.URLDecoder"%>
<%=(URLDecoder.decode("Produktgr%F6%DFe","UTF-8"))%><br/>
<%=(URLEncoder.encode("Produktgröße","UTF-8"))%><br/>
<%=(URLEncoder.encode("Produktgröße"))%><br/>
<%=(URLDecoder.decode(URLEncoder.encode("Produktgröße")))%><br/>
<%=(URLDecoder.decode(URLEncoder.encode("Produktgröße"),"UTF-8"))%><br/>
```

Produktgr?e

Produktgr%C3%B6%C3%9Fe

Produktgr%C3%B6%C3%9Fe

Produktgröße

Produktgröße

Any idea why I'm having this disparity with the languages and why JS/AS3 isn't behaving as I expect it to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*escape* is a deprecated function and does not correctly encode Unicode characters.  Use [*encodeURI*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) or [*encodeURIComponent*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), the latter probably being the method most suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is URL encoding your string using [Latin-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1) charset. Java is URL encoding it using [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8).

The URL encoding is really just replacing the characters/bytes that it doesn't recognise. For example, even if you were to stick with ASCII characters, `(` would be encoded as `%28`. You have the additional problem of character sets when you start using non-ASCII characters (any thing longer than 7 bits).

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this problem for hours on end...
My problem was a JQuery Ajax call like:

```
return $.ajax({
        url: '/author!getAuthorContent.action',
        type: 'GET',
        data : {author:name, 'content_type': ct || 'all', 'start': start || 0}
    });
```

'name' is a String which contains special characters like Jérôme-Serrano

For some reasons the way JS/JQuery was encoding these kind of special characters was incompatible and I couldn't decode it on Java BackEnd...

The solution was:

- Encode on JS side using `var econded = encodeURIComponent(name);`
- Decode them on Java side using `String decoded = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(econded ,"UTF-8");`

some refetences:
http://www.programering.com/a/MjN2ADOwATg.html
http://www.theerrormessage.com/2013/10/weird-characters-transmitted-to-and-from-server-through-jquery-ajax-call/