# How to send special characters in request to servlets

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, servlets, http-request-parameters

I am using a jQuery ajax command, which has the following data:

```
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
 ...
 data:"e=f_s&es="+JSON.stringify(email)+"&fr="+str
 ...
})
```

Where (email) can contain special character, for example it can be a string:

```
!#$%'&+-/=?^`*{|}~ch!#$%'/=?*^`{|}@mail.com
```

The reason why I allow such characters, is based on the following  [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-email-address)

The problem is, at some point on the server (Java EE application), it is messing up. The  special characters are not showing the boundaries of different request parameters. For example it is considering :

## '/

as a parameter.
I think I need to escape characters? (if yes how?)

What should I do to be able to send such a string from **javascript** to **java** ?

Comment: I've had a similar problem, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34345900/1864614

Comment: also in the future, java and javascript are very different; this question has nothing to do with java. just something to keep in mind; glad you got an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```
encodeURIComponent("!#$%'&+-/=?^`*{|}~ch!#$%'/=?*^`{|}@mail.com")
```

returning:

```
"!%23%24%25'%26%2B-%2F%3D%3F%5E%60*%7B%7C%7D~ch!%23%24%25'%2F%3D%3F*%5E%60%7B%7C%7D%40mail.com"
```