# Decode url which has been encoded in javascript

Tags: java, javascript

It's possible to decode url in java which has been encoded in javascript

***js:***

```
 params.url = encodeURIComponent(url);
```

Does anyone know the correct way of doing this?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp

Comment: @SimonStaton there is the same function in Java .?

Comment: Read the question wrong, assumed you meant js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `java.net.URLDecoder`.

But pay attention that there are several differences between java and javascript implementations.

For details take a look on:

[Difference in URL decode/encode UTF-8 between Java and JS/AS3 (bug!?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131520/difference-in-url-decode-encode-utf-8-between-java-and-js-as3-bug)

[Java equivalent to JavaScript's encodeURIComponent that produces identical output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607176/java-equivalent-to-javascripts-encodeuricomponent-that-produces-identical-outpu)

Answer (score 1):

Use the class [URLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html)

You can you use it for both encoding and decoding.